# Make dnd to update node and not move node

Tags: javascript, jquery, drag-and-drop, jstree

I am trying to use 2 jstree and the move function. My major concern is not to move to the node from one table to the next, but rather, drag and drop the node of one tree over the top of the other tree so that the node information is update ( which i do in the background using ajax calls )

The jstree to update changes to has the configuration that looks something like this

```
jQuery(document).ready(function (){

   var current_opperation = '';

jQuery("#tree1")
         .jstree({
                 "core" : {
                                "load_open" : "true"
                                },
                 "crrm" : {
                     "move" : {
                         "check_move" : function (data) {
                                var p = this._get_parent(data.o);
                                   if(!p) return false;
                                            p = p == -1 ? this.get_container() : p;
                                                if(p === data.np) return true;
                                                if(p[0] && data.np[0] && p[0] === data.np[0]) return true;

                                var copy_from_group = data.o.attr("id");
                                var match = copy_from_group.match(/gp_/);
                                }

                        },
                        "create":{
                                "label": "New"
                                },

                  },
                 "dnd" : {
                        "default_position" : "inside"
                        },
                 "types": {
                        "max_depth" : <% $depth %>,
                        'types':{
                        's':{
                                        'icon' :{
                                                'image' : '/icons/s16x16.png',
                                        },
                                },
                        'p': {
                                         'icon' :{
                                                'image' : '/icons/p16x16.png',
                                        },
                                },
                        'q': {
                                         'icon' :{
                                                'image' : '/icons/q16x16.png',
                                        },
                                },
                        'w': {
                                         'icon' :{
                                                'image' : '/icons/w16x16.png',
                                        },

                                },
                        },
                },

                 "plugins" : ["types","dnd","ui","crrm","themes","contextmenu","html_data","checkbox" ]

})
});
```

The tree to drag the node from has the config that looks something like:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){

        jQuery("#tree2")
         .jstree({
                 "core" : {
                                "load_open" : "true"
                                },
                 "crrm" : {
                     "move" : {
                         "always_copy" : "multitree",
                         "check_move" : function (data) {

                                 var p = this._get_parent(data.o);
                                   if(!p) return false;
                                            p = p == -1 ? this.get_container() : p;
                                                if(p === data.np) return true;
                                                if(p[0] && data.np[0] && p[0] === data.np[0]) return true;
                                var from = data.o.attr("group");
                                var to = data.r.attr("group");
                                var tocheck  = parseInt(to) + 1;
                                if(from == tocheck)
                                {
                                        return !(data.p === "before" || data.p === "after");
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                        return false;
                                        }

                                }

                        },
                        "create":{
                                "label": "New"
                                },

                  },
                 "dnd" : {
                        "default_position": "inside"
                        },
                 "types": {
                        "max_depth" : 7,
                        },

                 "plugins" : ["types","dnd","ui","crrm","themes","contextmenu","html_data","checkbox" ],
                 "contextmenu" : {'items' : customMenu }


        })
});
```

I have even managed to make sure that the tree doesnt move nodes only updates the nodes of the 1st tree. But i cannot seem to be able to remove the "X" that shows up when the jstree doesnt allow you to move nodes. How do i do that . And also how do i update that only one copy/move call is made and not everytime the node is hovering over nodes ( that is secondary)

Thanks in advance

Comment: Open this and click on `jsHint` http://jsfiddle.net/robschmuecker/jhncS/
Then this http://jsfiddle.net/robschmuecker/jhncS/1/ perhaps those `hints` might help.

Comment: It was just an extract from the code, so it might look like its not working . But it perfectly well does. I was just posting configs, as i didnt wanna give any other information. But thanks for the 'valuable' feedback :)